# Determine size difference of two unsigned int32 in bytes

Tags: c

So I have two unsigned 32bit ints, I need to find the difference between them in bytes.

Essentially the task could be solved by shifting the bits and determining how many bits are set it and compare the two values.

How exactly do I go about doing that?

Comment: There will be no size difference because 32bit ints are 32bits.

Comment: Ah, "in bytes"... so you want to think about non-8bit bytes?

Comment: It would be something like looking at the VLQ differences of the two ints.

Comment: What is VLQ difference?

Comment: 1. Implement a function that take one "unsigned 32bit int" and return its "size" 2. Use that to get "sizes" of two ints 3. Determine difference of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a function for calculating how many bytes an unsigned integer needs. Just use it on the two numbers and calculate the difference.

Edit: Thanks to Eric Postpischil for his patience with my sloppiness.

```
#include <limits.h>

int ByteCount(unsigned int n)
{
    int result = 0;
    
    while (n != 0) {
        result++;
        n >>= CHAR_BIT;
    }
   return result;
}
```